# How do I change the size of a JScrollPane in java

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, joptionpane

I have never used one of these before.I have only used normal JOptionPane boxes.This is what I have at the moment:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,new JScrollPane(new JList(uniqueWords.toArray())),"Unique Words",1);
```

where uniqueWords is an array list.The problem is the length of the dialog box is tiny.You can only see one line on screen at a time.How can I make it display more at a time.
Also is it possible to get rid of these notes and what causes them

```
Note: Files.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

**EDIT:**
I changed my code to this

```
JScrollPane jspane = new JScrollPane(new JList(uniqueWords.toArray()));
    Dimension size = new Dimension(1000,1000);
    jspane.setMinimumSize(size);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,jspane,"Unique Words",1);
```

but it is still displaying the same dialog box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "How can I make it display more at a time"

You can just override the `getPreferredSize` of the `JScrollPane`

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test3 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                    list.add("Hello, World " + i);
                }
                JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(new JList(list.toArray())) {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(200, 250);
                    }
                };
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pane);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

> "Also is it possible to get rid of these notes and what causes them"

You should do what it says and recompile with -XLint and it will show you details of the warnings

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should create the scrollpane outside,size it, and then add it.

```
JScrollPane scroll = ...
scroll.setMinimumSize( ... );

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, scroll, ... );
```

Hope, this helps :-)

Comment: I am trying to do this but I am just creating errors probably because I am not doing it right.Could someone please show me an example of exactly what I should be doing here

Answer (score 0):

```
JScrollPane jspane = new JScrollPane(new JList(uniqueWords.toArray()));
Jspane. SetMinimumSize(200);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,jspane,"Unique Words",1);
```

Is this what you expected ?